# How to add one array value to existing array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add one array values with  existing array values ,but i'm stuck how to add them

Array-1

```
[main] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [clientID] => 2
                    [maintenance_due] => 2016-05-09 00:00:00
                    [complete_maintenance] => 1
                    [description] => dfdff
                    [created_at] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                    [completed_on] => 2016-05-06 00:00:00
                    [name] => Bottel packing 
                    [type_id] => 1
                    [machinecode] => HITBTP001
                    [model_no] => ModelA
                    [created_date] => 2016-03-27 06:55:05
                    [updated_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                )

        )
```

Array-2

```
[dt] => Array
    (
        [dtm] => 0
        [edm] => 1
    )
```

I want like this

```
[main] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [clientID] => 2
                    [maintenance_due] => 2016-05-09 00:00:00
                    [complete_maintenance] => 1
                    [description] => dfdff
                    [created_at] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                    [completed_on] => 2016-05-06 00:00:00
                    [name] => Bottel packing 
                    [type_id] => 1
                    [machinecode] => HITBTP001
                    [model_no] => ModelA
                    [created_date] => 2016-03-27 06:55:05
                    [updated_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [dtm] => 0
                    [edm] => 1


                )

        )
```

I'm trying `array_push` function and also use foreach but isn't working .

Please suggest how can i do this.

Comment: Because element of array is object.

Comment: You're actually working with stdClass object here, not array.

Comment: How did you try `array_push()`?

Comment: @axiac    

            $arrayName = array('dtm' => $DaysToMaintenance,'edm'=>$EstDateforMaintenance);
             array_push($date, $arrayName)

Comment: `$main[0]->dtm = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `array_merge` function and conversion(casting) from array into object and vice versa(only for basic `stdClass` objects):

```
// $array1 is your first array with 'main' key
// $array2 is your second array with 'dt' key

$main_arr = (array) current($array1['main']);  // converting object into array
$merged = array_merge($main_arr, $array2['dt']);  // combining "properties"

$array1['main'] = [(object) $merged]; // saving object with additional properties back to the initial array

print_r($array1); // will give the expected output
```

Answer (score 0):

> [0] => stdClass Object

What you have under index `0` is not an `array`, but `object`. Unless it implements `ArrayAccess` interface, you cannot do this as you'd with regular array.

More on Objects: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: The question poster seems to have difficulties understanding basic concepts like arrays vs. objects and multi-level arrays. How can this cryptic answer help them when we don't even know how they attempted to use `array_push()`?

Comment: The answer points out exactly that. I assume that OP is able to figure out that it may mean either a bug or gap in the knowledge.

Comment: The added link to the official documentation (and not to some random SO question or answer) is worth retracting my down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$big_array` is the first array you posted and `$small_array` is the second array you posted then this should work:

```
$big_array['main'][0] = (object)array_merge((array)$big_array['main'][0], $small_array['dt']);
```

---

I dunno what your code looks like so this one might work automatically for you:

```
$main[0] = (object)array_merge((array)$main[0], $dt);
```

---

Per [Marcin Orlowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235698/marcin-orlowski)'s comment, below is the proper way to do this without the risk of overriding any classes or methods:

```
$main[0]->dtm = $dt['dtm'];
$main[0]->edm= $dt['edm'];
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning in bold, that this approach only makes sense in case of `stdClass` objects - in any other case you would just castrate the object out of any methods and turn it into dumb `stdClass` one.